# authentication forms reporting service asmx

Tags: service, reporting

- I had custom authentication forms on Power bi Report server by username and 
  pass (https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services)
- Now, I want to connect to ReportService2010.asmx for get report on report server but i do not know pass username and pass to authen

> ```
> ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
> rs.ListChildren("/", false)
> ```

==> error

> ```
> Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
> The request failed with the error message:
> --
> <html>
>   <head>
>       <title>
>           Power BI Report Server
>       </title><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Power BI Report Server 14.0.600.301" />
> <meta name="HTTP Status" content="500" />
> <meta name="ProductLocaleID" content="127" />
> <meta name="CountryLocaleID" content="1033" />
> <style>
>           BODY {FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; FONT-WEIGHT:normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR:black}
>           H1 {FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; FONT-WEIGHT:700; FONT-SIZE:15pt}
>           LI {FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; FONT-WEIGHT:normal; FONT-SIZE:10pt; DISPLAY:inline}
>           .ProductInfo {FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; FONT-WEIGHT:bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR:gray}
>           A:link {FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; COLOR:#3366CC; TEXT-DECORATION:none}
>           A:hover {FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; COLOR:#FF3300;
> ```
>
> TEXT-DECORATION:underline}
>                 A:visited {FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; COLOR:#3366CC; TEXT-DECORATION:none}
>                 A:visited:hover {FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; color:#FF3300;
>   TEXT-DECORATION:underline}
>
> ```
>       </style>
>   </head><body bgcolor="white">
>       <h1>
>           Report Server Error<hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver" />
>       </h1><ul>
>           <li>The Authentication Extension threw an unexpected exception or returned a value that is not valid: .
> ```
>
> (rsAuthorizationTokenInvalidOrExpired) Get Online Help
>
> - For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote
>     errors
>
> Power BI Report Server
>             
>         
>       --.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?